# Force a program to crash when it becomes unresponsive

Tags: windows-7, windows

We're running a program on Windows 7 which we're developing, but there are some bugs which cause it to become unresponsive occasionally, which windows detects and asks the user about.

As this is a standalone, no user interactivity (at least not keyboard and mouse), demonstration type application, we have code to restart the application if it outright crashes, but that isn't being activated when it simply freezes.

Is there a way to set windows so that if it detects that the program has become unresponsive that it will automatically kill it so our code will restart it?

Comment: Fix the bugs?  you need to add trace logging to your code so that you know what it's doing.

Comment: We already have extensive tracing in this sizeable project; fixing bugs is an ongoing issue but we need to deploy it despite this particular bug(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the following:

1. [Restarter](http://www.knas.se/Applications/Restarter.aspx)

   [image: 1]
2. [Restart on Crash](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2009/03/04/restart-on-crash/)

   [image: 2] [image: 3]